# What is the emotion for being glad of someone getting their just deserts

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word for the feeling of satisfaction when someone 'bad' gets punished? For example, when watching a movie and seeing the villain finally get defeated, the audience feels a sense of... what?

I thought I've heard of this word before but I can't find anything. *Schadenfreude* is a bit off and doesn't cover the "good, that guy finally got what he deserved" feeling (there's also a sense of moral superiority involved, I suppose?). I also found *vindictive*, but that doesn't convey the sense of satisfaction.

Comment: I would suggest that a lot of that sort of thing qualifies as society's 'self-satisfaction'. Behind every criminal there lurks a tragedy of some sort.

Comment: I still think that "schadenfreude" is the best term for this, if only because it tastes so delicious rolling off the tongue.

Comment: Related: [An idiom for deriving pleasure from another's suffering?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43771/an-idiom-for-deriving-pleasure-from-anothers-suffering)

Comment: It's not a word, it's [restaurant](http://www.justdesserts.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you're looking for a *feeling*, in either single noun or adjective terms, and I believe that we could say that the audience feels a sense of...

**justice**.

However, I think there are a few other common expressions that might also satisfy your general question:

*The audience felt that...*

**... he got his comeuppance.**

**... justice had been served.**

**... he got his just deserts**.

All of these convey the idea that someone who should be punished (e.g. the villain) did indeed get punished.

I believe merely uttering these expressions conveys the sense of satisfaction that you are asking about.

Comment: There are no *just desserts*, unless perhaps you’ve skipped the main course and that’s all you’re having. The phrase is ***just deserts*** without a double-*s*!

Comment: *comeuppance*, a punishment or fate that someone deserves. -You win, nice one.

Comment: +1 for *comeuppance*; *justice* is a much loftier and broader concept, but *comeuppance* captures the human satisfaction that *he got what was coming to him*.

Comment: _Comeuppance_ is a synonym to "just deserts".

Answer (score 1):

You can consider ***relief*** or ***righteous satisfaction***.

Also used is ***vicarious release*** because you experience this through the feelings of the protagonist.

> Seeing vengeance in a story provides us with a **vicarious release**, allowing us to harmlessly channel our vengeful anger that might otherwise get us into trouble. Seeing the villain punished gives a sense of **righteous satisfaction** and confirmation that right will always be done.
>
> <sub>http://changingminds.org/disciplines/storytelling/plots/polti_situations/vengeance_crime.htm</sub>

Also, there is ***excitation-transfer theory*** that explains that the anger towards the bad guy turns into satisfaction when the bad guy is punished.

> Excitation-transfer theory purports that residual excitation from one stimulus will amplify the excitatory response to another stimulus, though the hedonic valences of the stimuli may differ. The excitation-transfer process is not limited to a single emotion.
>
> **For example, when watching a movie, a viewer may be angered by seeing the hero wronged by the villain, but this initial excitation may intensify the viewer's pleasure in witnessing the villain's punishment later.**
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excitation-transfer_theory</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the personality of the person observing the villain's comeuppance, **self-righteous gloating** might well describe their motivation and emotional state.

Answer (score 0):

Avengement, retribution, vengeance, vengement, revenge or atonement may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The feeling I get is "vindicated"

Comment: Can you support this answer with any reference to explain how you would be vindicated?