# When you feel Grim Amusement

Tags: meaning

When one feels grimly amused,  exactly what kind of emotion is described? It seems to me that grim and amused are mutually contradictory so they do not conjure any consistent image in my mind. Thanks in advance for any explanations.

Comment: You mean [Schadenfreude?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43771/an-idiom-for-deriving-pleasure-from-anothers-suffering/43773#43773)

Comment: @Mazura - No, this isn't Schadenfreude.  This isn't related to other people's troubles.

Comment: The emotions that would give rise to a wry grin.

Answer (score 4):

I see no impediment to the ambivalence of having two contradictory feelings play in one's mind.  Perhaps this excerpt from *[The London Lancet](https://books.google.com/books?id=IRVAAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA487&dq=%22grim%20amusement%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBmoVChMIlsGZ-JnNxwIVyXE-Ch0PbA2Z#v=onepage&q=%22grim%20amusement%22&f=false)* from March 9, 1857 will provide adequate illustration:

> A wealthy old bachelor, with only distant relatives, or none at all,
>   and who has secretly made his will in favour of a charitable
>   institution, possesses a private source of **grim amusement** which,
>   although rather malevolent and bitter, may last him his life time.  He
>   chuckles over the disinterested attentions of expectant friends, or
>   ardent protestations of personal attachment from relations in hope of
>   thumping legacies.  The only check to his amusement is the thought of
>   his own unavoidable absence at the *denouement*, and inability to hear
>   the disappointed ones express their virtuous indignation that he should
>   "Die and endow a college or a cat."

The bachelor is amused at the antics of those sure-to-be-disappointed hangers-on expecting legacies, but the grim thought of his own death must attend the amusement.

Comment: nice touch, son of wharf.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing ***wryness***...

> [**wry**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wryness) *- **bitterly** or disdainfully ironic or **amusing***

As these dozens of written references to the [*fine line between laughing and crying*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fine%20line%20between%20laughing%20and%20crying%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) attest, it's not at all unusual to be grim/bitter at the same time as being humorous (*towards* others) or amused (*by* others, or by the grim situation).