# Laughing at other people's expense

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for when someone gets enjoyment out of someone else's misfortune or expense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An idiom for deriving pleasure from another's suffering](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43771/an-idiom-for-deriving-pleasure-from-anothers-suffering)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Schadenfreude*, a borrowed German word, is a common and concise way to say it.

> Enjoyment obtained from the troubles of others

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schadenfreude

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/epicaricacy) :

***epicaricacy*** 
(uncountable)

(rare) Rejoicing at or deriving pleasure from the misfortunes of others.

Comment: 'Epicaricacy' is a reaction to the more common 'schadenfreude' as a latinate calque, intended to replace the direct German loanword.