# Is there a name in English language for the feeling of being happy something bad happened to someone else rather than you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word in English language to express the feeling of being happy that something bad happened to someone else rather than you?

I can maybe describe it best as the opposite of [survivor's guilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_guilt), but I am really struggling to find the right term...

EDIT: There was a suggestion that my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43771/an-idiom-for-deriving-pleasure-from-anothers-suffering). 
However, they are different in the way that in my question there is no sadistic component to it, or gloating at the misfortune of others. The focus of my question lies in the fact that you feel happy bad thing  happened to the other person and **not you**. That's why I described it as the opposite of [survivor's guilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_guilt).

Comment: Context matters: 1. If you're a thief and you're pleased someone else got arrested for the crime you committed, that's schadenfreude with a mix of relief. 2. If you have the same risk of developing a life-threatening disease as a  siblings but only that sibling actually carries the defective gene, that would be survivor's guilt (one would hope).

Comment: You need to come up with a context and a SAMPLE SENTENCE (see the SWR tag for more info)

Comment: Hey @Mari-LouA, you gave a good example with the siblings, with the difference that the healthy sibling is feeling happy that his sibling is sick and not himself. So, again, opposite of survivor's guilt. Would you mind if I add your example in my question?

Comment: *…the healthy sibling is feeling happy that his sibling is sick…* Then if that's the case, the term you're looking for is definitely schadenfreude.

Answer (score 5):

It may not carry every nuance you're looking for, but we often use the German loan-word *schadenfreude* for something like this.

Dictionary.com defines the word as,

> satisfaction or pleasure felt at someone else's misfortune.

Comment: I think the OP wants to describe happiness that you feel not simply because something bad happened to someone else but also because you had been worried about the same bad thing happening to you. In other words, it's a combination of Schadenfreude and relief.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, Well, we didn't have a word for schadenfreude and had to borrow one, so it's not likely we have one for an even more specific situation. (Also, Wikipedia has a fairly extensive page on [schadenfreude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude) and that doesn't suggest any likely word for the more specific case)

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that there's another word doing what the OP wants, but only to point out that "Schadenfreude" doesn't quite do it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, fair enough. I've edited a bit.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think you understood the point when you described it as "a combination of Schadenfreude and relief".

Answer (score 1):

On the off-chance you're just blanking on a common word, possibly [relief?](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/relief)?

> alleviation, ease, or deliverance through the removal of pain, distress...

Comment: You can feel relief that something bad didn't happen to you, but would that word also include the situation where someone else was afflicted with the misfortune?

Comment: Often, you know something bad is going to happen, and it happening to someone else is the event that triggers the relief from anxiety: `Bob was relieved when the teacher called on Alice to present to the class, as he was unprepared.`

Answer (score 0):

[Epicaricacy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epicaricacy) : rejoicing at or deriving pleasure from the misfortunes of others.

I believe "Roman Holiday" has a similar connotation.